# Add Bootstrap error class to form field after Validation

Tags: validation, octobercms

I created a form in October CMS and would like to add the has-error class if there is a validation fail

`<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>

    <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
    <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" type="text" value="" required>
    </div>  <p class="error">{{ errors.first('first_name') }} </p>
    </div>
    </div>`

How do I call the error?  class="{% if errors %}has-error{% endif %}"

Answer (score 1):

I got this script working by changing the markup from

```
<p class="error">{{ errors.first('first_name') }} </p>
```

into

```
<p class="help-block"></p>
```

and change line 6 of the Jquery into

```
$help = $('.help-block');
```

Your markup isn't complete so it's hard to say what your problem is here. Are you using AJAX to submit this form, is the script properly included, what are your validation rules, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twig. 
Suppose you would want to add a 'has-error' class to your

```
    <div class="form-group">
```

Just rewrite that to

```
    <div class="form-group{{ errors.first('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
```

You're done; no javascript required!

Answer (score 0):

In the [Rainlab Relax Theme](https://octobercms.com/theme/rainlab-relax) there is a good example for this on its "Contact Form" page. It uses a neat little portion of JQuery code that can be tweaked and amended to your use case. As the Rainlab Relax example theme is published under the [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) I figure it is in order to paste the JS code for the used little JQuery handler here in full and leave it for you to figure out the inner workings and how to adjust its methods to your needs:

From the file `assets/javascript/app.js` in the Rainlab Relax theme:

```
/*
 * Implement nice invalid form fields
 */
$(window).on('ajaxInvalidField', function(event, fieldElement, fieldName, errorMsg, isFirst) {
    var $field = $(fieldElement).closest('.form-group'),
        $help = $('<p />').addClass('help-block')

    if (!$field.length) {
        return
    }

    event.preventDefault()

    if (errorMsg) {
        $help.text(errorMsg.join(', '))
    }

    $help.addClass('form-field-error-label')
    $field.addClass('has-error')

    // Prevent the next error alert only once
    $(window).one('ajaxErrorMessage', function(event, message){
        event.preventDefault()
    })

    if ($('.form-field-error-label', $field).length > 0)
        return

    $field.append($help)

    // Scroll to the form group
    if (isFirst) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $field.offset().top }, 500, function(){
            fieldElement.focus()
        })
    }
})
```

In short, this catches the **ajaxInvalidField** event that is triggered by the October Framework when the form handler on the server side throws a **ValidationException**, i.e. in this example (still from the Rainlab Relax theme code):

```
function onSubmit()
{
    $rules = [
        'name'     => 'required|min:2|max:64',
        'phone'    => 'required',
        'email'    => 'required|email|min:2|max:64',
        'comments' => 'required|min:5',
    ];

    $validation = Validator::make(post(), $rules);
    if ($validation->fails()) {
        throw new ValidationException($validation);
    }
}
```

The JQuery code above then basically just simply prevents the default event response (to show the error message in an `alert()`) and instead appends a `<p class="help-block form-field-error-label" />` containing the appropriate validation error message at the end inside an enclosing `<div class="form-group" />` that you would need in this example around your input, and also add the **has-error** class to that `<div class="form-group" />`, and some additional details that are probably not necessary here to go into detail about.

I guess you can probably figure out what you need from there. HTH. :)

Comment: Still can not get it to work. Just get alert that field show not be empty no has-error class

Comment: Oh, you are right. I'm sorry. My conclusions were wrong. The magic is not built into October, but is actually added through some JQuery code in a javascript file in the [Rainlab Relax theme](https://octobercms.com/theme/rainlab-relax) which I referred to. I will update my answer and include the JS code, which is actually quite short and neat, and quite sure very reusable and adjustable to one's needs.

Comment: I have updated my answer now, @Jaycbrf4 . Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I still can not get it to work. I was hoping that October would have something like this built in. Or at least an easy way of accomplishing it without custom JS.